# Bind Dialog Procedure as method to custom class

Tags: c++, winapi

I am trying to work my way around the WINAPI to implement the procedure of a modeless Dialog window as member of a custom class. I am not sure it is possible, but I hoped someone knew a way. The goal is to have a procedure with access to member variables of the custom Class

I know it is possible using normal windows.
**Example**:

```
//MyClass.h
class MyClass
{
    public:
    bool init( ... )
    static LRESULT CALLBACK    redirect(HWND hWnd, UINT msg,
                                          LPARAM lParam, WPARAM wParam);
    LRESULT myWndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT msg,
                      LPARAM lParam, WPARAM wParam);

    private:
    HWND m_MainHwnd;
}
```

By defining a static member function that redirects the pointer to the nonstatic actual procedure handling, the procedure can be a member function:

```
//MyClass.cpp
MyClass::init( ... )
{
    //Create the window class for the main Window//
    m_windowed = windowed;
    WNDCLASSEX wc;  //Create a new extended windows class

    wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX); //Size of our windows class
    wc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW; //class styles
    wc.lpfnWndProc = MyClass::redirect; //Default windows procedure function
    wc.cbClsExtra = NULL;   //Extra bytes after our wc structure
    wc.cbWndExtra = NULL;   //Extra bytes after our windows instance
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;   //Instance to current application
    wc.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_WINLOGO); //Title bar Icon
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);   //Default mouse Icon
    wc.hbrBackground = CreateSolidBrush(0xFFFFFF);  //Window bg color
    wc.lpszMenuName = NULL; //Name of the menu attached to our window
    wc.lpszClassName = m_windowName;    //Name of our windows class
    wc.hIconSm = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_WINLOGO); //Icon in your taskbar

    if (!RegisterClassEx(&wc))  //Register our windows class
    {
        //if registration failed, display error
        MessageBox(NULL, "Error registering Main Window class",
            "Error", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
        return false;
    }

    m_MainHwnd = CreateWindowEx(    //Create our Extended Window
        NULL,   //Extended style
        m_windowName,   //Name of our windows class
        m_windowName,   //Name in the title bar of our window
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE,   //style of our window | Make it              visible on showWindow cmd
        30, 30, //Top left corner of window
        width,  //Width of our window
        height, //Height of our window
        NULL,   //Handle to parent window
        NULL,   //Handle to a Menu
        hInstance,  //Specifies instance of current program
        this    //used for an MDI client window
    );
}
```

See the line in the setup in WNDCLASSEX: **wc.lpfnWndProc = MyClass::redirect;**? This is valid because the the following implementation of the redirect static function:

```
MyClass::redirect(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, LPARAM lParam, WPARAM wParam)
{
    if (msg == WM_CREATE)  SetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWL_USERDATA, (LONG_PTR)((CREATESTRUCT FAR *)lParam)->lpCreateParams);
    MyClass * pObject = (MyClass*)((LONG_PTR)GetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWL_USERDATA));
    if (pObject) return pObject->MyWndProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);

    //return the message for windows to handle it
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd,
        msg,
        wParam,
        lParam);
};
```

This lets you implement the MyWndProc ( ... ) exactly like any other member method.

Now! I really want to be able to do the same thing to my Modeless Dialog box - because it's rather important that it knows the member variables of "MyClass". Also - I like that I can design it and redesign it as I like ( If I have to use normal windows - It'd be tedious to design it all in code. )

Is it possible?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it's possible to use this method with a dialog box, in more or less the same way.

Instead of using `WM_CREATE` to store the `this` pointer you use `WM_INITDIALOG`. Note that the user data is passed to `WM_INITDIALOG` in `lParam` itself - there are no structures to dereference like there is with `WM_CREATE`.

You can store the pointer in `DWLP_USER` which is a pointer-size window data slot available to the owner of the dialog box.

The final difference is simply return `FALSE` if the data pointer hasn't been assigned yet - you don't call `DefWindowProc` from a dialog procedure.

```
class MyClass
{
public:
        static INT_PTR CALLBACK dlgRedirect(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
        LRESULT myDlgProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
}

//...
HWND hwndDlg = DialogBoxParam(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_MYDIALOG), hwndParent,
    MyClass::dlgRedirect, reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(this));

//...
INT_PTR CALLBACK MyClass::dlgRedirect(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (uMsg == WM_INITDIALOG) SetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, DWLP_USER, lParam);
    MyClass* pThis = reinterpret_class<MyClass*>(GetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, DWLP_USER));
    if (pThis) return pThis->myDlgProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
    return FALSE;
}

INT_PTR MyClass::myDlgProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    // real dialog procedure here
}
```

Comment: Thank you SO much.. This was exactly the mod I was looking for! Can I ask if you knew this already or do you have a source?  Just out of curiosity.

Comment: You have no idea how happy I am! I almost gave up! THANK YOU!

Comment: @Silverback I think it's a well-known technique, I've been using it for years. Can't remember where I first picked it up.

Comment: This technique is demonstrated in other parts of SO, like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5519767/wrapping-the-dialog-procedure) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12582511/use-class-member-as-wndproc-dlgproc-with-or-without-global/12584581)

Comment: Okay - Sure. Thank you. I've never seen the fix for dialog boxes before - but thank you for your help!
@Raymon Chen - Thank you Mr Chen :)

Comment: @Silverback: The technique has been well established for more than two decades. It's more or less what MFC does, with the exception that MFC stores the class instance pointer already, before any messages are sent (by virtue of a CBT hook). This allows for a window procedure without any conditionals.

Comment: @IInspectable Wow. Well that's good to know. It's weird that I didn't find any material on the matter. Thanks for the info - There's obviously a hole in my knowledge about dialog boxes.

Comment: @Silverback I added an answer to the linked duplicate (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12582511/use-class-member-as-wndproc-dlgproc-with-or-without-global) which shows how to use templates to make this technique more seamless.

Comment: Wow - thanks a lot. :-D maybe I can learn something more from it then. Thank you for the trouble!!!